# Vuex - updating data in store from child $emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a Vue app that can either randomize a title and subtitle OR manually edit these two values through a custom input component. When a user decides to edit, their input should then display on save those results on the parent component.

I have the randomizer and child component emitting the updated headings working, but having a troubled time updating the parents and state to display the custom input title and subtitle on save and getting a "undefined" error for both title and subtitle when I placed console logs in updateTitleAndSubtitle() in the actions section of the store.

The objective of this code challenging is to return the new values to the store and be able to display the custom inputs while having the randomizer handy whenever a user decides to use that instead.

Any direction on what I'm doing wrong or missing would be much appreciated. I've been reading article after article around Vuex and Vue2 for 3 days now with 2 months of experience using Vue.

---

Custom Input Child Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label for="title">Edit Title: </label>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="title"
      :updateTitle="updateTitle"
      v-model="inputTitle"
    />

    <label for="title">Edit Subtitle: </label>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="subtitle" :updateSubtitle="updateSubtitle"
      v-model="inputSubtitle"
    />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CustomInput',
  props: {
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,
  },
  computed: {
    updateTitle() {
      console.log('updateTitle: ', this.title);
      return this.title;
    },
    updateSubtitle() {
      console.log('updateSubtitle: ', this.subtitle);
      return this.subtitle;
    },
    inputTitle: {
      get() {
        console.log('set title: ', this.title);
        return this.title;
      },
      set(title) {
        console.log('set title: ', title);
        this.$emit('input', title);
      },
    },
    inputSubtitle: {
      get() {
        return this.subtitle;
      },
      set(subtitle) {
        console.log('set subtitle: ', subtitle);
        this.$emit('input', subtitle);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <main class="home-page page">

    <div v-if="!editMode" class="display-information">
      <div class="title">
        <span class="bold">Title: </span>{{title}}
      </div>

      <div class="subtitle">
        <span class="bold">Subtitle: </span>{{subtitle}}
      </div>

      <div class="controls">
        <button id="randomize-button" class="control-button" @click="randomizeTitleAndSubtitle">
          Randomize
        </button>
        <button id="edit-button" class="control-button" @click="onEdit">Edit</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div v-else class="edit-controls">

      <CustomInput
        :title="title"
        :subtitle="subtitle"
        @update="v => onSave(v)"
      />

      <div class="controls">
        <button id="cancel-button" class="control-button" @click="onCancel">Cancel</button>
        <button id="save-button" class="control-button" @click="onSave">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import CustomInput from '@/components/CustomInput.vue';
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    CustomInput,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editMode: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['title', 'subtitle']),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['randomizeHeadings', 'updateHeadings']),
    onEdit() {
      this.editMode = true;
    },
    onCancel() {
      this.editMode = false;
    },
    onSave(v) {
      this.editMode = false;
      this.title = v.title;
      this.subtitle = v.subtitle;
      this.updateTitleAndSubtitle(v);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.randomizeHeadings();
  },
};
```

Vuex Store:

```
import randomWords from 'random-words';

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    title: '',
    subtitle: '',
  },
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_TITLE(state, value) {
      state.title = value;
    },
    UPDATE_SUBTITLE(state, value) {
      state.subtitle = value;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    randomizeTitle({ commit }) {
      const newTitle = randomWords();
      commit('UPDATE_TITLE', newTitle);
    },
    randomizeSubtitle({ commit }) {
      const newSubtitle = randomWords();
      commit('UPDATE_SUBTITLE', newSubtitle);
    },
    randomizeTitleAndSubtitle({ dispatch }) {
      dispatch('randomizeTitle');
      dispatch('randomizeSubtitle');
    },
    updateTitleAndSubtitle({ commit }) {
      const payload = {
        title: this.title || null,
        subtitle: this.subtitle || null,
      };

      commit('UPDATE_TITLE', payload);
      commit('UPDATE_SUBTITLE', payload);
    },
  },
  modules: {
  },
});
```

Comment: I can not see ```updateHeadings()``` action in your "Vuex store". If you mean ```updateTitleAndSubtitle``` action, I think the name of them must be [the same](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions-in-components). Also if you put the code of your ```CustomInput``` component in your question, maybe other developers could help you better.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @hamid-davodi, added the custom input code for review and updated the updateHeadings() to match the updatedTitleAndSubtitle action.

Comment: Currently getting a "Computed property "title" was assigned to but it has no setter." error message and two undefined ~ each for title and subtitle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code in my local development environment and find out that you need a lot of changes in your codes to work better. Here is the new vuex store code:

> vuex store:

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        title: '',
        subtitle: '',
    },
    mutations: {
        UPDATE_TITLE(state, value) {
            state.title = value;
        },
        UPDATE_SUBTITLE(state, value) {
            state.subtitle = value;
        },
    },
    actions: {
        randomizeTitle({ commit }) {
            const newTitle = randomWords();
            commit('UPDATE_TITLE', newTitle);
        },
        randomizeSubtitle({ commit }) {
            const newSubtitle = randomWords();
            commit('UPDATE_SUBTITLE', newSubtitle);
        },
        randomizeTitleAndSubtitle({ dispatch }) {
            dispatch('randomizeTitle');
            dispatch('randomizeSubtitle');
        },
        updateTitleAndSubtitle({ commit }, inputUser) {
            /* I changed the structure of this action to work correctly */
            console.log(inputUser);
            commit('UPDATE_TITLE', inputUser.title);
            commit('UPDATE_SUBTITLE', inputUser.subtitle);
        },
    },
    modules: {
    },
});
```

Also here is the new `Parent component` code:

> Parent component:

```html
<template>
  <main class="home-page page">

    <div v-if="!editMode" class="display-information">
      <div class="title">
        <span class="bold">Title: </span>{{title}}
      </div>

      <div class="subtitle">
        <span class="bold">Subtitle: </span>{{subtitle}}
      </div>

      <div class="controls">
        <button id="randomize-button" class="control-button" @click="randomizeTitleAndSubtitle">
          Randomize
        </button>
        <button id="edit-button" class="control-button" @click="onEdit">Edit</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div v-else class="edit-controls">

      <CustomInput
          :title="title"
          :subtitle="subtitle"
          @titleEvent = "myFuncTitle"
          @subTitleEvent = "myFuncSubTitle"
      />
      <!--
      I removed this part from your component.
      @update="v => onSave(v)"

      and also added custom events (titleEvent and subTitleEvent) to the component
      -->

      <div class="controls">
        <button id="cancel-button" class="control-button" @click="onCancel">Cancel</button>
        <button id="save-button" class="control-button" @click="onSave">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import CustomInput from '../components/CustomInput.vue';
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  components: {
    CustomInput,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editMode: false,
      /* defining new data for handling "cancel" button functionality */
      temporaryTitle: "",
      temporarySubTitle: ""
    };
  },

  computed: {
    /* defining setter and getter for each computed value separately */
    title: {
      // getter
      get: function () {
        return this.$store.state.title;
      },
      // setter
      set: function (newValue) {
        this.$store.commit('UPDATE_TITLE', newValue);
      }
    },
    subtitle: {
      // getter
      get: function () {
        return this.$store.state.subtitle;
      },
      // setter
      set: function (newValue) {
        this.$store.commit('UPDATE_SUBTITLE', newValue);
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    /* changing the name of actions according to the names defined in "store" */
    ...mapActions(['randomizeTitleAndSubtitle', 'updateTitleAndSubtitle']),
    onEdit() {
      this.editMode = true;
      this.temporaryTitle = this.$store.state.title;
      this.temporarySubTitle = this.$store.state.subtitle;
    },
    onCancel() {
      this.editMode = false;
      this.$store.commit('UPDATE_TITLE', this.temporaryTitle);
      this.$store.commit('UPDATE_SUBTITLE', this.temporarySubTitle);
    },
    myFuncTitle(event) {
      console.log(event);
      /* we could not set values to "computed" properties, if we had not defined "set: function ..." for them above.  */
      this.title = event;
    },
    myFuncSubTitle(event) {
      this.subtitle = event;
    },
    onSave(v) {
      this.editMode = false;
      console.log(v); /* "v" is not related to your data. notice the console */
      // this.title = v.title;
      // this.subtitle = v.subtitle;
      const payload = {
        title: this.title,
        subtitle: this.subtitle,
      };
      this.updateTitleAndSubtitle(payload);
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.randomizeTitleAndSubtitle();
  },
};
</script>
```

And finally here is the code of new `Custom Input` component:

> Custom Input:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <label for="title">Edit Title: </label>
    <input
        type="text"
        id="title"
        v-model="inputTitle"
        @input="$emit('titleEvent', $event.target.value)"
    />
    <!-- emitting event like above code for each input -->

    <label for="title">Edit Subtitle: </label>
    <input
        type="text"
        id="subtitle"
        v-model="inputSubtitle"
        @input="$emit('subTitleEvent', $event.target.value)"
    />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CustomInput',
  props: {
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,
  },
  computed: {

    inputTitle: {
      get() {
        console.log('set title: ', this.title);
        return this.title;
      },
      set(title) {
        console.log('set title: ', title);
      },
    },
    inputSubtitle: {
      get() {
        return this.subtitle;
      },
      set(subtitle) {
        console.log('set subtitle: ', subtitle);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I tried to comment some changes to the codes, but the main changes are related to changing the name of **mapActions** actions according to the names defined in "store" and also **provide a setter** for computed properties.

I suggest that you read more in vue and vuex documentations, especially the page that is related to [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) and [computed setters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) and [vuex actions](https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions), if you have problems with my codes.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I ended up figuring out what I was doing wrong and did something VERY similar to what you posted. Added a empty object in the data to take in the object the custom input would $emit changes from and then passed that through the onEdit() method I had. Then took that object and dispatched it to updateTitleAndSubtitle action in the store where I dispatched the title and subtitle values to two new actions called setTitle and setSubtitle. Guess I didn't need to add that extra step comparing what I have to yours! I'll upvote and accept your answer though :) thanks